# OpenCV java VideoDevice constructor unknown exception

Tags: java, opencv, constructor

So I made a simple video-capture program, it compiles  just fine, but when I run it I get this error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Exception: unknown exception
    at org.opencv.videoio.VideoCapture.VideoCapture_2(Native Method)
    at org.opencv.videoio.VideoCapture.<init>(VideoCapture.java:54)
    at jonta.Cam.main(Cam.java:35)
```

The code it's referring to:

```
VideoCapture camera = new VideoCapture(0);
```

I'm trying to access the built-in cam in my laptop and I'm running win10, what's wrong?

Comment: Have you tried other device numbers such as 1 or 2? 
Also do a try{}catch and print the stacktrace and error message to get some more information on why it crashes.

Comment: I have, but 0 should work since I only have one device. Also no new information gathered with try{}catch.

Comment: Are you running matching bit detpth of a JDK, OpenCV and OS at either 32 or 64 bits? I mean not mixing of bit depths in the chain?

Comment: What platform?  Have you tried using other methods of VideoCapture like reading an image file or video?

Comment: @EinarSundgren Everything is 32bit.

Comment: @medloh I do use the methods later in the code, but the error message points to the constructor.

Comment: I believe there are other versions of the constructor that take a file instead of a device id.

Comment: Which IDE are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, hope this will solve the problem in OpenCV 3.0.0

```
VideoCapture camera = new VideoCapture();
camera.open(0);
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution! Explanations of why are extremely useful to people looking through questions after the fact. A correct answer is much more useful to the site if it includes some explanation.